# Pytorch tensor equality not making sense

Tags: pytorch

```
tensor(1.0000, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)

tensor([1.])
```

Why are these two tensors not equivalent in pytorch?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: when converting to numpy,

```
assert torch.sum(state_alphas).detach().numpy() == 1, torch.sum(state_alphas).detach().numpy()
AssertionError: 0.9999994
```

For some reason even though the Tensor is displayed as 1.000... it is not quite equal to 1.

Comment: By default, floating point tensors are displayed with 4 digits of decimal precision and 0.9999994 differs from 1. below that threshold.

Comment: What is the threshold difference for equality?

Comment: None, as you would expect. If you want to have approximate equality you can use [`torch.all_close`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.allclose).